# Extracting specific data from ArrayList

Tags: java, android, hibernate, rest

Hi I am trying to create a user login where the user enters their username and pin and then my REST services retrieves the username and pin to check that it matches. At the minute I have it working although this by using a GET request sending through employeeId as parameter but this means I have to hardcode the employeeId in my android app.

I am now trying a POST to getRecords() which has returned all of the users and their details in an ArrayList.

Here is my getRecords() method in my REST service:

```
 @Override
public List<UsersTable> getSpecificRecords(UserTableCriteria entity) {

    boolean criteriaSet = false;
    int firstResult = 0;
    List<UsersTable> entityReturned;

    // check if web side sent in any record retrieval instructions and use
    // them instead
    if (entity.getFirstResult() != null) {
        firstResult = entity.getFirstResult();
    }

    // if maximum results to be returned sent by web application 
    // is less than normall allowed use that value
    if (entity.getMaxResults() != null && entity.getMaxResults() < ApplicationConstants.MAX_RETURNED_RESULTS) {
        maxResults = entity.getMaxResults();
    } else {
        maxResults = ApplicationConstants.MAX_RETURNED_RESULTS;
    }

    if (!session.isOpen()) {
        this.session = HibernateUtil.getApplicationSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    }

    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.clear();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(UsersTable.class);


    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(entity.getUserName())) {
        if (entity.getUserName().contains("*")) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("userName", entity.getUserName().replace('*', '%')));

        } else {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("userName", entity.getUserName()).ignoreCase());
        }
        criteriaSet = true;
    }

    // set the sort order of the returned records
    criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("userName"));

    criteria.setMaxResults(maxResults);

    criteria.setFirstResult(firstResult);

    // validate there is at least one value to search on and run the query
    if (criteriaSet) {
        entityReturned = criteria.list();
        session.close();
        return entityReturned;
    }

    session.close();

    return new ArrayList<>();

}
```

EDIT: Controller Code

```
@POST
@Secured
@Path("/")
@Produces("application/xml, application/json")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getSpecificRecords(@HeaderParam("securityToken") String token, UserTableCriteria entity) {

    // retrieve a list of entities based on specific criteria
    UsersTableList entityList;

    try {

        entityList = usersTableBO.getSpecificRecords(entity);
        LOGGER.debug("Successful single key table get specific was processed");

    } catch (NotFoundException ex) {

        LOGGER.debug(MessageFormat.format("Single key table get Specific failed because of error: {0}", ex.getMessage()));
        return returnEntityResponse(Response.Status.NO_CONTENT);

    }

    return returnEntityResponse(entityList, Response.Status.OK);

}
```

How can I achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: Try to draw attention to where exactly you need help.

Comment: @soufrk perhaps there is an IF statement that extracts only userNames from the array list of all the details?

Comment: I'm confused why can't you just return the List from the controller?

Comment: yeah I get the list but this includes all data from every employee. I am trying to extract just username(s)

Comment: what im essentially trying to achieve is a GET request that uses a username as the parameter but I know GET requests are only neccesarilly by IDs